# Ansible Mount Absent - Error unmounting /var: umount: /var: device is busy

Tags: ansible, mount

I am trying to use Ansible to remove `/var` from `/etc/fstab` without attempting to unmount the partition, I will use a reboot to make the change take affect :

```
- name: Remove Default /var Mount
  mount: state=absent src=/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_var name=/var fstype=ext4 opts=defaults,acl,user_xattr,nosuid
```

When I run the ansible playbook it throws an error :

```
TASK [partitions : Remove Default /var Mount] **********************************
fatal: [docker-001]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false, 
"failed": true, 
"msg": "Error unmounting /var: umount: /var: device is busy.\n (In some cases useful info about processes that use\n the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))\n"}
```

The Ansible Mount module documentation says :

`absent` and `present` only deal with fstab but will **not** affect current mounting.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mount_module.html

So it should not be attempting to unmount the partition, it should just remove it from the `/etc/fstab` file.

I am running ansible :

**ansible --version**

```
ansible 2.0.1.0
  config file = /Users/xxxxxx/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Comment: Yes, that sounds kind of odd, I gave the `mount` module code a look and I found this: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/stable-2.0.0.1/system/mount.py#L312
absent does actually try to unmount the partition, that's why you're getting the error

Answer (score 0):

You might be standing in the mounted directory. Thus keeping the device busy. Make sure no terminals are standing in the working (mounted) directory.